# wp_list_pages not working in 3.5

Tags: php, wordpress

Since updating to 3.5, my code for outputting a list of subpage is no longer working.

```
<?php if(  $post->post_parent ) {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&sort_order=ASC&sort_column=post_date");
} else {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&sort_order=ASC&sort_column=post_date");
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what might have caused this to stop outputting in 3.5?

Comment: Turn on [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_list_pages()` wasn't changed in WordPress 3.5. So the reason for your change of behavior might be found elsewhere, maybe because of WordPress 3.5 new behavior, but occurring a few lines before in your code. Can you check the execution with a break point at each step before? Or can you simply give us your code including the previous parts ? (considering the problem is probably not located in this small section you have isolated).